# Configure Relative path in HTML when inside a folder

Tags: html, path

Currently i am doing a website admin redesign where i need to include some css and js files into the header, but i am confused how to do this,

admin path is

```
www.xxx.com/admin/
```

what i want to include is in the top level

```
www.xxx.com/css/style.css
```

I know i can use the full path but i dont want to hard code the full path like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.xxx.com/css/colorbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

So i am looking for a URL independent solution to use to include them.

may be ../../ but not sure this works though ? any idea ?

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />`

Or

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/colorbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start your URL with a slash and use the full path:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/colorbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />`

Answer (score 1):

On Unix systems, "." is the current directory, and ".." is one directory up.
This means that for your problem, the correct path would be:

```
../css/style.css
```

or the whole line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/colorbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Link them like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You just gave answear in Your question :)

For relative paths use `../` this will go one folder up. So for excample:
file placed in `www.xxx.com/admin/` path used in this location: `../css/style.css` in result path will be: `www.xxx.com/css/style.css`

One thing i'm not sure is if this method is used with full adress of a web will it be working properly.

I know that this (as i can see) is not a solution fo You but while i'm a PHP programmer i like to use full paths based on servers direct paths (using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`). This saves me a lot of time with paths while for example moving web from one server to another and from my experiaece i can tell that it is worth of implement in any project.